# Autofill password not working on iTunes Connect?

Tags: google-chrome, app-store-connect

Every time I connect on iTunes Connect (OS X 10.10, Chrome) I have to fill in my password, which is very tiring. Chrome autofills all my passwords, why doesn't it work there? Even with the 'remember me' check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new login of iTunes Connect uses an AJAX form for signing in but does not use a `<form>` tag for it which prevents Chrome from saving the password.

I was so annoyed that I built a tiny [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itunes-connect-save-passw/fanebhhbhodomldojlachocjkafjkpdk) to fix this issue and allow Chrome to save the password.

Comment: it is not working on my side... how can I help make it work ? (Im an experienced programmer but no experience with chrome extensions)
console gives two errors : Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading ... and Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-options'.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for helping on this! The error messages originate from the website, not from the extension. Could you please right-click on the email address field and choose "Inspect"? Then in the HTML tree which just opened you go upwards until you find the first "<body>". It should look like the following image, including the "<form>": https://www.dropbox.com/s/q2ge336g53qn42k/Screenshot%202015-12-11%2010.08.14.png?dl=0

Comment: still not working and yet I see the same as on your picture

Comment: So the extension is working yet Chrome doesn't offer to save the password? This will be difficult to fix since it works for me without problems. The obvious approach would be to double-check everything, starting with http://superuser.com/a/573625. Also make sure that on chrome://settings/passwords no apple.com website is on the "Never saved" list. Beside that I can only suspect that either a bug or another extension is causing the issue.

Comment: actually it did ask once to save the password but doesn't autofill it anymore

Comment: Does it when you select the account's email address from the drop-down list?

Comment: Is this extension still available? I have the same problem.

Comment: @EtienneJuneau no, I have pulled it because they've changed App Store Connect  completely so it no longer worked and it also works fine for me now even without the extension 

Comment: @fluidsonic thx! Too bad. Still doesn't work for me. I have to fill out the darn password every time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cross-browser, cross-platform solution. No addons required, but it takes 3 minutes and some html knowledge:

## Adding a temporary fake form

Specific instructions here are for Chrome and Firefox (on macOS), but it should be extremely similar for other browsers and other platforms (replace <kbd>Cmd</kbd> with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>). Also works with some sites other than App Store Connect.

1. Right click the input field (username) and select <kbd>Inspect</kbd> or <kbd>Inspect element</kbd>.
2. Remember or write down the value of `name` or `id` of that field. Repeat these steps also for the password input field.
3. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to select any element to replace it with a fake input field.
4. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit that element's source.
5. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the whole element's source.
6. Paste the following instead of the element's source:

```
<form method=post>
  <input name=IDENTIFIER>
  <input type=password name=PASSWORD>
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```

7. Replace `IDENTIFIER` and `PASSWORD` with the ones you got from step 2.
8. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply your changes. You can now close the developer menu.
9. Type your username and password into the 2 new input fields that appeared.
10. Click <kbd>Submit</kbd>. You might get an error or nothing visible might happen.
11. Now your browser should offer to save the credentials in a popup or maybe you need to click a key shaped button in the corner of the address bar to get that popup.

---

Original source with extra background [here](https://superuser.com/a/1084364/290915).
Almost same answer to a different question [here](https://superuser.com/a/1489906/290915).

## Firefox 70.0 or newer

Firefox has now added the option to manually add a login to your built-in password manager (called Firefox Lockwise) which you can find when you type `about:logins` to your address bar. Click the <kbd>Create New Login</kbd> button at the bottom left. You should put `https://appleid.apple.com` as the Website address.